# Capybara trim down the link and getting ActionController::RoutingError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, tdd, capybara

I have a link in my ruby on rails project which redirects the user here: `https://blah.com/files/form/anonymous/api/library/142270db-...`, but when running the command

```
bundle exec rpsec spec/features/*
```

When I simulate the click of the link I get:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
```

No route matches [GET] "/files/form/anonymous/api/library/142270db-...

Why is Capybara triming down the link and then getting a routing error?

Comment: If you're using the racktest driver it ignores host name because it assumes all URLs point to your app since that all it can access

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that is correct. If you wanna wrap that up in an answer I will go for accepting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't mention a specific driver, I assume you're using the racktest driver.  It ignores the host name and assumes all URLs point to your app since that's all it can access.